# Проблемы кода выводит на русском языке, как фиксить?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что проблемы кода выводит на русском языке, как фиксить?

Comment: Почему вы считаете это проблемой?

Comment: наверное потому что SO значительно больше чем SO на русском

Comment: (◕‿◕)  〓D